# Jet Airways has ceased operations. Can I get my ticket refunded?

Tags: cancellations, refunds, jet-airways

A short while ago, a friend of mine booked an international itinerary on Jet Airways for the summer, flying out of India.

This morning, it appears that Jet Airways has failed to find a buyer for a 75% stake and as such has ceased all international and East Indian operations. (**Update as of April 18, 2019:** Jet Airways ceased *all* operations after it failed to secure emergency funding from lenders.)

They have tried contacting the airline, but to no avail. According to the airline, it is re-accommodating passengers onto other airlines' flights, but I'm not sure of that due to the lack of contact and the airline's current financial state.

If the airline fails to rebook them onto another flight, what can they do to get a refund? (They are an Indian citizen.)

Comment: Did your friend pay by credit card?

Comment: @Traveller I don't know their payment method, but I did tell them they can file a chargeback.

Comment: Related question about an other airline, answers may be helpful: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134703/wow-air-has-ceased-operation-can-i-get-my-tickets-refunded

Comment: @Willeke I read that question, but what's different here is that the airline still *technically* is under operation, whereas WOW ceased all operations.

Comment: @Willeke They have now ceased all operations, but apparently it's a temporary suspension and "not permanent". I think that if the airline ceases operations permanently, we can close this as a dupe, but if not, we should leave it open.