# Regarding Jet Airways flight cancellation

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, new-delhi, jet-airways

I book my flight from Delhi to Paris, my journey schedule is as follows:
onward journey 21st April 2019 (Delhi-Bombay-Paris) and return journey 30 April 2019 (Paris-Bombay-Delhi) in **Jet Airways**.
Now **Jet Airways** cancelled my domestic flight (from Delhi to Bombay, on 21st April'19) and (from Bombay to Delhi, on 1st May 2019) due to the operational issue. I book my flight through MakeMyTrip (MMT) site.
In this case, can MMT take responsibility of that Jet Airways cancellation and provide me alternate flight or they will refund my flight charges?

Comment: Have you contacted MMT for their advice?

Comment: Related: [Jet Airways has ceased international operations. Can I get my ticket refunded?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135605/jet-airways-has-ceased-international-operations-can-i-get-my-ticket-refunded)

Answer (score 2):

I just read MMT's "User agreement" which you automatically agree to when you sign up (I bet you clicked a box that said "agree to user terms"?). Sadly very few consumers bother to read the small boring print that uses many legal terms that always makes it confusing.

To sum up what you agreed to (or what they made sure will solidly protect them from having to do anything by obligation): They have ZERO liability and clearly state they do not take responsibility for any issues caused by 3rd party vendors.

What is even more troubling is the fact you currently are not able to book yet alone find Jet Airways anywhere on their "booking engine" The link to 9W on their site does not even directly refer to the airline's site.

My advise to you :

Try and contact them, but do not be confrontational. remind yourself that you likely will get nowhere by trying to demand or threaten to seek legal advise or similar. They know how it works. I would approach it by telling them you booked the trip to Paris as something you saved up for over a long time and will be devastated if your dream to visit France was to be ruined due to this....get them to feel sympathy and inspire them to assist.

IF that and all else fails, Grab your computer and get a twitter account. Bombard them with Tweets, again do not threaten but let them and the world know that you hope MMT will not fail you and ruin your hard earned experience. Do the same on their Facebook page. You will find how amazingly fast companies who spend huge amounts of marketing dollars and rely on social media to drive business will act on negative or unfavourable activity. I have successfully done this a few time for service issues with my mobile phone provider, even the brand maker of our kitchen stove were quick to reconsider a warranty repair they originally refused.....

Good luck my friend. Next time use a travel agent you can look in the eyes. remember if it sounds too good to be true it always is....

Comment: Please do not sign your answers with your location, that would make a good answer into spam. I guess you are a travel agent, if so you can register your account and mention that on your 'about me' part of your profile.